# writing every new char element to a single file if it's overwritten

Tags: java

I need to write some char element to a .txt before it gets overwritten by me in runtime.

I've tried doing like this:

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    char c = keyEvent.getKeyChar();//this gets overwritten in runtime
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
        out.print(c);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But as you may guess, if i type "java", only 'a'(last char) will be inside of test.txt. Also, when typed "rrr", same letters need to be saved too.
Sorry for bad English.
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: So what is it that the file should contain? And who overwrites what and where? And why is that important anyway?

Comment: File should contain everything i type. I type 'p' and it gets to char c. After that it(char c) needs to be written to a txt file. but if i press another symbol in the same runtime, let's say, 'q', then char c will now be overwritten and will contain 'q'. txt file is expected to have 'pq' in it. but it only has the last character i typed(it is 'q' if to follow the example i've given here).

Comment: I am not into JAVA but from what I see. you are creating the `out` object new over and over again. So I guess the file gets reopened and overwritten every time. Also you never `out.close()`, which is probably not very good (If it is closed on exit of the method, I'd at least consider it bad style...but this is a personal opinion). Either there is an append option or you should open the `PrintWriter` somewhere else and use this method only to write to an existing stream. For sure there are many options. Dunno which one would be most JAVAish.

Comment: I haven't written out.close(); here but i have it in actual code because it doesn't matter(it doesn't change the situation). i also have found a solution by myself sitting at the university on boring lessons!

Comment: Good to see that you found a solution. Concerning the `close()`; I consider this part of a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). And as I said, you'll need a type of `append`; now you append to a string instead of a file, why not. The question would be how to incorporate your solution into the original code, as this is not clear from your post. You also may post the complete solution as an answer and accept your own solution.

Comment: Instead of editing the solution in the question, you should post an answer to it, not adding `[SOLVED]` in the question's title. This is a Q&A site, not a forum. I rolled back your edit and posted it as an answer. If you want you can copy-paste it and post it yourself, then accept it. After that I'll remove mine or you can accept mine (however you want). But be sure to accept any. To notify me you can write `@Frakcool` in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OP's edits in the question:

SOLUTION!

```
String s = "";//initializing a variable
s = s.concat(String.valueOf(c));//two-liner elegant solution!
```

i had stuck on this for two days, so if you were thinking about this more than me  and/or have found more ellegant or effactive way, let me know.

Full code example:

```
String s = "";
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) {
    char c = keyEvent.getKeyChar();
    String s = s.concat(String.valueOf(c));
    try {
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("test.txt");
        out.print(s);
        out.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException x) {
        x.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I have come to by myself in three days. Rechecked SO too late. Marking this as a correct answer as it helped me.